# QGIS Points show up for one field/value but not another

Tags: qgis, rendering

When I added a csv file as a delimited layer, it shows up on the map fine:
[image]

I classified and changed the symbology of one field/value for bottom depth data and it worked fine too:
[image]

When I tried to do the same for another field/value that's surface depth data, only about half the points show up:
[image]

I did the same steps for both bottom and surface so I'm not sure why there is an issue. I even saved the symbology style that I used for the "bottom" data points that worked, and it doesn't work for the surface data.
[image]
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Typical Dissolved Oxygen levels in surface sea water are, as far as I know, up to around 8 mg/l. The way you have set up your color coding, values above 6.79 mg/l will not be shown. Just adjust the upper limit for your values or add a new class what ever makes sense in your case.

(In general, if some points does not show up, the first thing to check is if the color coding accidentially excludes some value)